# Digital signature tab not seen for executable developed in VC in VS2005 IDE using /keyfile and /LN as additional option in linker

Tags: c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, digital-signature

I am trying to sign an executable developed in VC in VS2005 IDE using /keyfile and /LN as additional option in linker. 
But after compiling I do not see the Digital signature tab in the exe in windows 8.1.

Comment: Strong-naming a .NET assembly doesn't have anything to do with adding a code signing certificate to an executable.  You do that with signcode.exe and the certificate costs money.

Comment: You are right. I need to use a pfx instead.